# Delphi open all Files in Project Manager at once

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe8

When the IDE starts it normally opens the main form while all other .pas files can be openend through the project manager. I want to load alle those files at once. Is there any way to open all .pas files shown in the project manager at once?

If so can I automate this to get this done each time I open a (specific) project?

This would speed up working on large projects, where you normally have to click on each .pas file to load it into the main editor.

Of course I could simply write a batch to start each .pas in the project directory, but is there a more elegant way to get this done by the IDE itself?

Maybe there's a way to start this batch after the IDE starts up using some extra lines in the .dproj or .dpr or something?

Comment: try pressing ctrl + f12 after opening the main form

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've never tried selecting all of them.. damn sorry for asking this question^^

Comment: Alternatively, enable saving the IDE state, then make sure all files are open before closing the project. Then reopening the project will open all previously opened files

Comment: Tools->Options->Environment Options, *Autosave options* section, check *Project desktop*. Open all the files you want open, then save your project. This will create a <yourproject>.dsk file in your project's directory, that will be read when you open the project. (If you ever want the old behavior, you can uncheck the box described above and then delete this .dsk file.)